# Parameterizing file name in MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Is there a way to dynamically specify a file name in the LOAD DATA INFILE? Can it be parameterized like for instance (syntax may be incorrect) LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'?

Answer (score 2):

A citation from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a table at a very high speed. The file name must be given as a literal string.

That means that it can not be a parameter of a prepared statement. But no one forbids to make the string interpolation while the statement is just a string in your PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this feature is not yet supported in MySQL and is currently listed as bug/feature request #39115 http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39115

Answer (score 2):

Or you can make a temporary copy of the file (BATCH example):

LOAD_DATA.bat

```
COPY %1 TempFileToLoad.csv
mysql --user=myuser --password=mypass MyDatabase < ScriptLoadMyDatabase.sql
DEL TempFileToLoad.csv
```

the SQL (for info) :

ScriptLoadMyDatabase.sql

```
load data infile 'TempFileToLoad.csv' IGNORE
into table tLoad
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@DateCrea, NomClient, PrenomClient, TypeMvt, @Montant, NumeroClient)
set DateCrea = str_to_date(@DateCrea, '%Y-%m-%d'), Montant = (round(@Montant / 1000)*2) ;
```

And finished to put a link to the BAT file in SendTo windows folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if it can be used in a script; you can do some thing like this with php:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "pwd", "db");
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


$sql = "CREATE TABLE number1 (id INT PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,data TEXT)";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
} else {
printf("<br>%s",$mysqli->error);

}

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$filename = "data.csv";

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$host$uri$filename' INTO TABLE number1";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

} else {
printf("<br>%s",$mysqli->error);    
}
// Close the DB connection
$mysqli->close();

exit;
%>
```

If the file is in the same folder as the script just use $filename a instead of $host$uri$filename. I put this together quick from a couple scripts I'm using, sorry if it doesn't work without debug, but it should be pretty close. It requires mysqli.